# How to pass NSMutableDictionary from one viewController to another View controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

**firstviewcontroller.m**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *json;

.h
@synthesis json;

    viewdidload()

    {
        nslog(@"%@",json);
    }
```

**secondviewcontroller.h**

```
firstviewcontroller *FVC = [[firstviewcontroller alloc]init];

FVC.json = @"My NSMutableDictionary"
```

This is my code, in `firstviewcontrol` `NSMutableDictionary`  value is null. How to solve this?

Comment: can you show some additional code

Comment: Add the code of property declaration of the `firstviewcontroller`

Comment: Use storyboard and segue and you can pass data via segue delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to load your xib file using `[NSBundle mainBundle]` approach and the first object in returned array is your controller. Then assign your dictionary object and then push using `navigationcontroller`.

```
    NSArray * array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<your xib file name without .xib extension>" owner:self options:nil];
secondViewConroller *cntrl = [array objectAtIndex:0];
cntrl.json = <your dictionary data>;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cntrl animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Write in your `"secondViewConroller.h"` file

```
@property (nonatomic, Strong) NSMutableDictionary *json;
```

And pass it as in `"firtstViewConroller.m"`

```
NSMutableDictionary *temJSONDic = ....

secondViewConroller *FVC = [[secondViewConroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewConroller" bundle:nil];
FVC.json = temJSONDic;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:FVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I used this but not working getting not null value. Actually, I used .xib file

Comment: Use secondViewConroller *FVC = [[secondViewConroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewConroller" bundle:nil];